# How to make Iframe run in the context of the main? DMZ - within network mix

Tags: asp.net, iframe, iis-7

Here is the scenario.
DMZ box has the main application written ASP.NET running on IIS7(machine1)
We have another box which is within the network(machine2).
This box has JBOSS and PDF builder code.

Webpages on machine1 has iframe within which calls are made to machine2 for rendering PDFs.
Now as expected, this works when we are within the network as machine2 is reachable.
But, outside of the network iframe calls fail.
We know we can solve this by taking machine2 outside of network, making it as DMZ.

Question can this be avoided?

Can we somehow(IIS setting,..) make iframe calls route through machine1(DMZ) or run in the parent context?

Pardon me if the question is dumb,

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a "reverse proxy". In IIS7+, you can use the "URL Rewrite Module" and the "Application Request Routing" module to do this.

Here's an article that tells how to set this up: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

The client browser will only see your machine1 in the HTML, but that server can forward certain web requests to machine2 to render the PDf.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the interest of time we had to move part of the code to machine1 to get the work done. But, looks like URL Rewrite might work as well.